# Did Karna's dāna really save his life?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, karna

**Background**:

- I saw in a Karna movie and also read a Mahabharata book, where, towards the end, Karna was injured in his chest by Arjuna's arrow and the last arrow to kill him actually turned in to a flower so it doesn't injure Karna.
- Lord Krishna explains the above as: Karna did *dāna* all his life so the fruits of that dāna is now saving him.
- So Lord Krishna turned himself into a brahmin and asked Karna to give him [Krishna] fruits of all his [Karna's] *dāna* and only after that does Karna actually die.

**Question**:
Is the above life-saving story of Karna, due to his dāna, really true or is it just shown like that to praise Karna's benevolent nature?

Answer (score 3):

No the story about Karna's death (last arrow turning into flower not injuring him) is not true. Karna was shattered psychologically at the time of his death. 
The story about Brahmana is partially true. The Brahmana took the kavacha and Kundala from Karna because without them Karna was vulnerable in war.

> 'At that time, when hour of Karna's death had come, Kala, approaching
>   invisibly, and alluding to the Brahmana's curse, and desirous of
>   informing Karna that his death was near, told him, "The Earth is
>   devouring thy wheel'. Indeed, O foremost of men, when the hour of
>   Karna's death came, the high Brahma weapon that the illustrious
>   Bhargava had imparted unto him, escaped from his memory. And the earth also began to devour the left wheel of his car. Then in consequence of that foremost of Brahmanas, Karna's car began to reel, having sunk deep into the earth and having been transfixed at that spot like a sacred tree with its load of flowers standing upon its elevated platform. When his
>   car began to reel from the curse of the Brahmana and when the high
>   weapon he had obtained from Rama no longer shone in him through inward
>   light, and when his terrible snake-mouthed shaft also had been cut off
>   by Partha, **Karna became filled with melancholy**.'

Mahabharata Karna Parva Section XC

Comment: gandopadhyay I have another question, "If karna entered the war with his Kavasha and kundalas he will be invincible in battle"."INVINCIBLE IN BATTLE" is  dharma or adharma (answer with scriptures please)

Comment: @sakthi Beng "Invincible in battle" is not dharma or adharma..In the 3 worlds no one gets anything for free..everyone has to earn it either by tapas(penance) or by sacrifice done either in the present birth or in the previous births..

Comment: @Rickross IF "INVINCIBLE IN BATTLE" is not dharma or adharma  then why should Shri ramachandra have to kill vali and say about his boon as "Half of enemies power will be absorbed to vali". is not moral. So friend I think that  there must be a law for battle to be followed.

Comment: @sakthi If someone has earned such invinciblity boons by his severe penances then i'm not sure how can that be either Dharma or adharma..he earned it by legal means..Now whether he can use it during battles(dharmayuddha) is some other issue..but then again if he is not allowed to use in battles then what's the use of that boon to him afterall?

Comment: @Rickross boon or anything Must be according to rules of world if against it life's ultimate goal MOKSHA cannot be achieved. so only lord ramachandra attacked vali from behind. So friend  there must be rule for entering war or battle with or without INVINCIBILITY.

Comment: @Sakthi boons are given mostly by Lord Shiva ,Goddess Shakti Brhama and Vishnu..and they are all all-knowing..So,u can't charge any of them for giving "incorrect" boons..But i'm actually not quite sure about the rules of war..May be what u say is right..because Rama is saying so..

Comment: Guys. First thing Karna got his `kawacha` and `kundala` not from his penances, but as the last kavacha of his previous demon birth. And ya it is adharma to be `INVINCIBLE IN BATTLE` that is why the reason lord Hanuman was on the flag of Arjuna's chariot and lord Krishn wowed not to fight as even they were INVINCIBLE.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava First of all its not about karna alone..I am talking about invincibilty boons in general..and i'm aware that karna is having his kavacha and kundal from his birth..In general most of the asuras do severe tapas for acquiring either immortality or invincibilty boons..while the 1st one is not possible to acquire they often end up gettig the 2nd one..now if the rules of battles are such that they can't even use those boons on grounds of being illegal then whats the purpose of those boons in the first place?..

Comment: ..And what do u mean by Krishna didn't participate in Kurukshetra war because he is invincible? ..Krishna did fight in wars during his lifetime....BTw i am not aware of what rules for war are....I have read some of those in brief as found in the Agni Purana but not in detail..

Comment: @Rickross yup Sri Krishn fought in wars in his lifetime but didn't participate in the battle of Mahabharat.:) The boons are awarded to asuras for their great tapas. Just like a gold medal or a award for a great work. But it doesn't mean the gold medalist should degrade others right? This is what I meant.:)